# Vue.js Server Side Rendering: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I am using a package which uses `document` and `window`. I want to make my website have server-side rendering without changing too much code. For `window is not defined`, I use `window-or-global` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/window-or-global) and it solves my problem.

However, when it comes to `document`, I actually don't find anything useful. My idea is try to find out when the server or the client is rendering. I will only execute the code with `document` when the client is rendering. Is there any way to do that?

P/S: I am using Vue.js 2.0. The package I am using is fine-uploader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fine-uploader)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also using Vue Server Side rendering in a new project, and what I do for this kind of problem is that I check if I am in the browser environment or in the server one using:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // We are in the browser
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
const Vue = require('vue');
Vue.prototype.$isServer
```

or from within a component

```
this.$isServer
```